# My https website is redirecting to my old http website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

a while ago i made a copy of my wordpress website and restore it on a ssl/https verficated account and since that, my new site have been redirecting to http. 
I've tried with the htaccess code and it doesn´t work. I'll paste my code below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://voladurascontroladas.com/$1 [R,L]




# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.5.20]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTPS_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: As far as I connect to your website, it running fine with HTTPS and not redirect to HTTP. The HTTP version redirect to HTTPS well.

Comment: +1 - Your site is redirecting to the HTTPS version correctly. I think the issue might be to do with caching on your end (possibly VPS or your local machine)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I don't know what's happening, it redirects but the https:// security lock appear gray instead of green, do you guys see the same?